# Python3 circular library import (module not defined)

Tags: python

I am building a python library, yet can't seem to solve this rather trivial import error. My folder structure is as follows:

```
./examples/somecode.py
./library/code/specific/__init__.py and other files for this submodule
```

my somecode.py looks something in the lines of

```
from library.code import specific
... do things with specific ...
```

I get **specific not defined error**.

but only if I am in the examples folder. Interestingly enought, the code works if I start the interpreter from the ./ folder.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

the library is installed with python3 setup.py install

Comment: Well your computer can not find the folder **library** if you are inside examples, you have answered that yourself ?

Comment: Pardon, I installed the library with python3 setup.py install.

Comment: this setup.py is in `./` or in `./library` ?

Comment: or, put in another way, is `from code import specific` working?

Comment: Yes, other code works fine, it is in ./ folder